# $X_{n} = X_{n_{i}} + X_{n_{j}}$ where $0< n_{i}, n_{j} < n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

First of all, I'm not good at mathematical notation, so the title might not represent exactly what I want to achieve.

What I want to do is to calculate a number, $X_n$. However, $X_n$ can only be the sum of two previous numbers, where 
$$X_1 = 1, X_2 = 2$$

So, if $X_n = 7$, then the following would be one solution: $$X_1 = 1, X_2 = 2, X_3 = 3, X_4 = 6, X_5 = 7, where X_n = X_5$$ (I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if something is unclear)

Anyway, the goal is to make $n$ as small as possible. I've been at this problem for hours and I can get it somewhat small just breaking it down into smaller steps, starting with the $X_n$ and working backwards. For example, if $X_n$ is 15, then the sequence could be $1,2,3,6,7,14,15$. If $X_n$ = 31, then you could take the previous sequence, double the last number and add 1, so the sequence would be $1,2,3,6,7,14,15,30,31$. However, that would not be the optimal solution in this case, as $1,2,3,6,7,14,28,31$ requires less numbers.

Note that this is homework and I don't want the solution written out explicitly for me. I just want some kind of hint or a nudge in the right direction. I feel like I'm onto something but I can't seem to find a pattern that is true for all numbers. Also, what area of math would this belong do?

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: $X_4 = 6$ but in no way can it be the sum of two previous numbers.

Comment: 3+3 is allowed. The rule is $X_n = X(_ni) + X_(nj)$  where $0 < ni, nj < n$ , so $ni$ and $nj$ can be the same number.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I suggest working backwards. For any fibonacci number, the shortest sequence is just the fibonacci number. I am thinking that if a number is between the $n$th and $(n+1)$th fibonacci term, there is a sequence of length $(n+1)$.

Comment: I messed up the formating in the previous comment. It should read $X_{n} = X_{n_{i}} + X_{n_{j}}$ where $0< n_{i}, n_{j} < n$

Comment: @YunusSyed So this would be classified as a fibonnaci sequence?

Comment: Fibonacci sequences are defined by taking the sum of the two immediate previous terms.

Answer (score 1):

A possible algorithm is based on the base-2 representation of your target, call it
$$X = \sum_{i=0}^m x_i 2^i := (x_m\ldots x_1x_0)_2$$
The sequence starts with $1, 2$. We then make $X_k = 2^k$ for $k = 1 \ldots m$.
Finally, build the number one bit at a time. This last step requires $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i - 1$ steps, so we reach $X = X_n$ with
$$n = \lfloor\log_2 X\rfloor + \mathrm{nset}(X)$$
Where $\mathrm{nset}(X)$ is the number of set bits in the binary representation of $X$.

**Example: $X = 7$**

$\lfloor\log_2 7\rfloor = 2 = m$ and $7 = 111_2$ with $\mathrm{nset}(7) = 3$ so the algorithm produces $n = 2 + 3 = 5$ with the sequence:

$$1, 2, 4 = 2+2, 3 = 1 + 2, 7 = 3 + 4$$

**Example: $X = 31$**
Here $31 = 11111_2$, $m = 4$ and $\mathrm{nset}(31) = 5$, so we need $n = 9$
$$1,2,4,8,16,3,7,15,31$$

Unfortunately, this proves that the algorithm is not optimal (You found $n=8$ with $1,2,3,6,7,14,28,31$).

Comment: Thanks for the input! But as you said, 31 can be found with $n = 8$.

Comment: @Lobs002 I was mildly surprised when computing the second example, to be honest :) Numbers of the form $2^n - 1$ are the worst case for this algorithm, so maybe it will help for other numbers...

Comment: Hmm. So creating one algorithm for any number that is $2^n - 1$ and another algorithm for all other numbers, and then working backwards could maybe work?

Comment: Not sure actually. I'll think about it when I have a moment